# R - How to exclude cases based on the number of NA values in certain variables

Tags: r, subset, missing-data

I have a dataframe with 22 variables (I can't post it here since the data is confidential). I need to remove all cases that have all NAs in variables 4 through 22. So, if a certain case has at least one non-NA in variables 4 through 22, I have to keep it. It's not relevant if there is or is not a NA value in the first three variables, but I also need to keep those three variables in my dataframe.

I'm trying this code:

```
df<-df[rowSums(is.na(df[,c(4:22)]))==19]
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, rowSums(is.na(df[, c(4:22)])) == 19) : 
undefined columns selected
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to do? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using number `19`? Shouldn't it be `nrow(df)` as MKR's answer points out?

Comment: Because I want to exclude a row if it has 19 NAs, since 22 minus first three variables equals 19

Comment: @J.Doe Hence you should use `!=` condition so that which ever column has less than 19 `NA` it will return `TRUE` and hence those columns will be selected.

Comment: Yes, but why is it important how many NAs does a column have? I'm interested in removing rows.

Comment: @J.Doe You are pretty close in that case. Just add an `,` after condition `== 19` and you are there:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very much near to solution. You can try the `colSums` on columns `4:22`. Also, include 3 `TRUE` to keep first 3 columns selected.

```
df[c(rep(TRUE,3),colSums(is.na(df[4:22])) != nrow(df) )]
```

If OP wants to exclude `rows` with all `NA` values in column 4:22 then solution could be:

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df[,c(4:22)])) != 19, ]
```

Applying above solution to a dataframe with 8 columns as:

```
df[c(rep(TRUE,3),colSums(is.na(df[4:8])) != nrow(df) )]
#    ID Status V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1   1      0  1  0  0  0  1
# 2   1      0  1  0  0  0  1
# 3   1      1  1  1  1  1  1
# 4   2      0  2  0  0  0  2
# 5   2      1  2  1  1  1  2
# 6   2     NA  2 NA NA NA  2
# 7   3      0  3  0  0  0  3
# 8   3      1  3  1  1  1  3
# 9   3     NA  3 NA NA NA  3
# 10  3     NA  3 NA NA NA  3
```

**Sample data.frame**

```
   ID Status V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1   1      0  1  0  0  0  1 NA
2   1      0  1  0  0  0  1 NA
3   1      1  1  1  1  1  1 NA
4   2      0  2  0  0  0  2 NA
5   2      1  2  1  1  1  2 NA
6   2     NA  2 NA NA NA  2 NA
7   3      0  3  0  0  0  3 NA
8   3      1  3  1  1  1  3 NA
9   3     NA  3 NA NA NA  3 NA
10  3     NA  3 NA NA NA  3 NA
```

Comment: Sorry, running this code leaves me with first three variables only. I need to keep all 22 variables, but remove cases which have all NAs in variables 4 through 22.

Comment: @J.Doe That's clarifies it. We can tweak the solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, that function just returns the same dataframe. I'm trying to understand your code; could you explain why are you using colSums instead of rowSums?

Comment: It probably returns the same dataframe because there is no variable that has all NA's in it. He is using colSums because that gives the sum of the variable, not the row (rowSums). I'd say his answer is spot on.

Comment: That's true, there is no variable which has all NAs; I don't need to exclude variables, but cases. I need to remove all cases which have all NAs in variables 4 through 22.

Comment: @J.Doe You can have a look at my sample data.frame which explains how it works. Actually if all values in a column are `NA` then count should match with row-count. We dont need to cases hence `!=` condition.

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding, I am not interested at all if there is a column (variable) which has all NAs. I am interested in rows (cases) which have all NAs - but it's only important if they have all NAs in columns 4 through 22, otherwise I would use the following:

df<-df[complete.cases(df), ]

Comment: @J.Doe Ohh. In that case you should try `df<-df[rowSums(is.na(df[,c(4:22)]))== (ncol(df)-3), ]`

Comment: @J.Doe You have just missed just a `,` in your solution.

Comment: Thank you! It works now, I missed a comma and an ! at the beginning. The correct line is:

df<-df[!rowSums(is.na(df[,c(4:22)]))==19,]

Comment: @J.Doe You did good job in providing info. You can write it as `df[rowSums(is.na(df[,c(4:22)]))!=19,] `

Comment: Even better! Thanks!